# SESSION VS GET in API for Php

Tags: php, session

I know it's a dumb question but I just wanted to confirm what to use better in cases like creating an API and passing the output to an external site which also uses Php.

Let's say for example, I have this URL as my API

```
http://{my website}/{my folder}/apiv1.php/{some number}/{Command Code}/{Command Pin}/{Start Date}/{End Date}
```

Now this will return an array ranging from hundreds to thousands maybe.

I want to pass the array to an external website which also uses Php. It's not a big website though but I was thinking if it is better to pass the return and the external website is going to retrieve it by either SESSION or GET.

Which is better in this kind of situations: GET like $_GET or Session like $_SESSION  ?

Thank you for all the comments in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean `$_POST` (instead of `$_SESSION`)? Don't really get what it is you're asking, though.

Comment: NO it's session. I used the Session since the array is so big. ^_^

Comment: Session variables are for retaining variables across different scripts or multiple invocations of a script. `$_GET` is for getting parameters from the caller. Sessions only work with a client that processes cookies, which usually just means a browser (although server applications can emulate it).

Comment: The `$_SESSION`-super global is actually an array as well. But asking for `$_SESSION` or `$_GET` is like asking if you should go for a walk or green, it doesn't makes any sense in the context of your question. I think you need to be more specific... explain your proposed flow, where the data comes from, what you do with it and how you pass it along to the external site.